# Turning a FutureProvider into a Provider

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I use `FirebaseAuth` for the authentication and I've defined the following provider:

```dart
final _authStateChangesProvider = StreamProvider<User>(
    (ref) => ref.watch(authServiceProvider).authStateChanges);
```

The database depends on the User, so I can create it only after the user has signed-in. The problem is that the database creation is async, so its provider has to be a FutureProvider.

```dart
final databaseFutureProvider = FutureProvider<Database>((ref) {
  final authStateChange = ref.watch(_authStateChangesProvider);
  final user = authStateChange.data?.value;
  if (user != null) {
    return FirestoreDatabase.create(user: user);
  }
  throw UnsupportedError("The database cannot be accessed before the sign-in");
});
```

This would make the code throughout the app more cumbersome. I'd like to make the `databaseFutureProvider` a simple `Provider` to make the app's code cleaner. How could it be done?

**EDIT**

It would be nice to have the database creation be part of the authentication process, so that the `authStateChangesProvider` will fire only after the database creation. Something like the following:

```dart
final authStateChangesProvider = FutureProvider<User>((ref) {
  final authStateChanged = ref.watch(_authStateChangesProvider);
  final user = authStateChanged.data?.value;
  if (user != null) {
    // await the creation of the database provider
  }
  return user;
});
```

In this way only the `authStateChangesProvider` will be a FutureProvider. But I'm pretty new to Riverpod and I'm not sure if and how I can create a provider inside another provider.

Comment: You've already done it - as in, you are not using async/await in your FutureProvider, so just change it to Provider.

Comment: Sorry, maybe it wasn't clear in the question, but the `FirestoreDatabase.create(user: user)` function is async, so I can't just change `FutureProvider` with `Provider`.

Comment: I've edited the question. I hope it's clearer now what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come up with a solution that probably isn't the best, but I'll post it here so that others can benefit from it or hopefully could improve it.

I've created a new `ScopedProvider`.

```dart
final databaseProvider =
    ScopedProvider<Database>((ref) => throw UnimplementedError());
```

Then I've created a new widget that will be put on top of the widget tree that will need the sync access to the database. This widget will just display a loading view while the database is being created and then overrides the `databseProvider`.

```dart
class DatabaseWidgetBuilder extends ConsumerWidget {
  final Widget Function(Database) childBuilder;

  DatabaseWidgetBuilder(
      {Key key, @required Widget Function(Database) this.childBuilder})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, ScopedReader watch) {
    final databaseAsyncValue = watch(databaseFutureProvider);
    return databaseAsyncValue.when(
      data: (database) => ProviderScope(
        overrides: [databaseProvider.overrideAs((watch) => database)],
        child: childBuilder(database),
      ),
      loading: () => Scaffold(
        body: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
      ),
      error: (_, __) => Scaffold(
        body: Center(child: Text("Database Error")),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```